# Mvc 3 form post parameter: How can I reach ddl with name="Attribute.AttributeID" by a parameter in a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, parameters

I have a dropdownlist that looks like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.Attribute.AttributeID,
        new SelectList(Model.Attributes, "AttributeID", "Name")
)
```

In my controller I've tried parameters like attributeId and attribute_attributeId, this is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int productId, int attributeId)
```

(Btw, I'm also receiving the ProductID which is in the query string)

The output of my ddl is ... id="Attribute_AttributeID" name="Attribute.AttributeID" ...

I've tried this also:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.Attribute.AttributeID,
        new SelectList(Model.Attributes, "AttributeID", "Name"),
        null,
        new { id = "attributeId", name = "attributeId" }
    )
```

But then the id just changes and not the both...

So my question is how can I be able to reach the dll without having to write something like **x => x.SelectedAttributeID** in the ddl.

Comment: What do you see in the HTTP POST?

Comment: I don't know how to see the HTTP POST, where can I see the HTTP POST?

Comment: I see for example Attribute.AttributeID=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Attribute attribute)
{
   // attribute will have the attributeId property
}
```